# rearrange an array element based on list in python

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have got a 2D array `a` with size `2, 1403` and a list `b` which has 2 list.

`a.shape = (2, 1403) # a is 2D array, each row has got unique elements.`

`len(b) = 2 # b is list`

`len(b[0]), len(b[1]) = 415, 452 # here also both the list inside b has got unique elements`

all the elements present in `b[0] and b[1]` is present in `a[0] and a[1]` respectively

Now i want to rearrange elements of `a` based on elements of `b`. I want to rearrange such that all the elements in `b[0]` which is also present in `a[0]` should come in the ending of `a[0]`, meaning new `a` should be such that `a[0][:-len(b[0])] = b[0]`, similarly `a[1][:-len(b[1])] = b[1]`.

**Toy Example**

`a` has got elements like `[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]`

`b` has got elements like `[[5, 9, 10], [2, 6, 8, 9, 11]]`

`new_a` becomes `[[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,11,12,5,9,10], [1,3,4,5,7,10,12,2,6,8,9,11]]`

I have written a code which loops over all the element which becomes very slow, it's shown below

```
a_temp = []
remove_temp = []
for i, array in enumerate(a):
    a_temp_inner = []
    remove_temp_inner = []
    for element in array:
        if element not in b[i]:
            a_temp_inner.append(element) # get all elements first which are not present in b
        else:
            remove_temp_inner.append(element) #if any element present in b, remove it from main array

    a_temp.append(a_temp_inner)
    remove_temp.append(b_temp_inner)

a_temp = torch.tensor(a_temp)
remove_temp = torch.tensor(remove_temp)
a = torch.cat((a_temp, remove_temp), dim = 1)
```

Can anyone please help me with some faster implementation that works better than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming *a* is a `np.array`, *b* is a `list` you can use

```py
np.array([np.concatenate((i[~np.in1d(i, j)], j)) for i, j in zip(a,b)])
```

Output

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  6,  7,  8, 11, 12,  5,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  3,  4,  5,  7, 10, 12,  2,  6,  8,  9, 11]])
```

Can be micro-optimized if *b* contains empty `lists`

```py
np.array([np.concatenate((i[~np.in1d(i, j)], j)) if j else i for i, j in zip(a,b)])
```

In my benchmarks, for `np.arrays` with less than ~100 elements converting `.tolist()` is faster than `np.concatenate`

```py
np.array([i[~np.in1d(i, j)].tolist() + j for i, j in zip(a,b)])
```

---

Data example and imports for this solution

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    ])
b = [[5, 9, 10],
     [2, 6, 8, 9, 11]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

```py
index_ = np.array([[False if i in d else True for i in c] for c, d in zip(a,b)])
arr_filtered =[[np.extract(ind, c) for c, d, ind in zip(a,b,index_)], [np.extract(np.logical_not(ind), c) for c, d, ind in zip(a,b, index_)]]
arr_final = ar = np.array([np.concatenate((i, j)) for i, j in zip(*arr_filtered)])
```